# How to show ng-checked condtion with &&

Tags: angularjs

I have a code in which am trying to use ng-checked= `<input type="radio" ng-checked="x.overAllStatus ==='A' && x.overAllStatus ==='b'">` condition, but condition is failing to show checked if it is true

```
<input type="radio" ng-checked="x.overAllStatus ==='A' && x.overAllStatus ==='b'">
```

`ng-checked="x.overAllStatus ==='A' && x.overAllStatus ==='b'"`

My expected result is to store checked value

Comment: How could `x.overAllStatus` be equal to `A` **and** `B` at the same time?

Comment: a want a result as :if that condition meets radio button to be checked

Comment: So I think you need to change `&&` to `||` (If `x.overAllStatus` equals to `A` **or** is equal to `b` )

Answer (score 0):

You can condition in view with

```
ng-checked="$val1 == 'val' && $val2 == 'val2'"
```

or with function called in `ng-checked`, like

```
ng-checked="check()"
```

Here is an example I made for you:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("personController", function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [
         {driver: 'driver1', age: 19, gender:'male', canDrive:false},
          {driver: 'driver2', age: 19, gender:'female', canDrive:false}
         ];

   
   //change fun
   $scope.changeGen = function(gen, item){
     item.gender = gen;
      $scope.check(item);
   }
   
   //change fun
   $scope.changeDriveSts = function(item){
      //toggle val
      item.canDrive = !item.canDrive;
   }
   
   //init check
   $scope.check = function(item){
    if(item.age > 18 && item.gender === 'female'){
     item.canDrive = true;
    } else {
     item.canDrive = false;
    }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <p>Conditional ng-radio.</p>
    <div ng-controller="personController">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.driver">
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.age">
      </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" ng-change="changeGen('male', item)"  ng-model="item.gender" value="male" />
            Male            
          </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" ng-change="changeGen('female', item)" ng-model="item.gender" value="female" />
            Female 
          </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" ng-click="changeDriveSts(item)" ng-init="check(item)" ng-model="item.canDrive" ng-value="true" />
            Can drive {{item.canDrive}}
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**
Removed the ng-model from example, as Bill commented "ng-checked should not be used together with ng-model".

**Update:**

updated the jsfiddle, we have there two drivers set:

```
      {driver: 'driver1', age: 19, gender:'male', canDrive:false},
      {driver: 'driver2', age: 19, gender:'female', canDrive:false}
```

Both drivers have drive status as false something we check while we do the loop (ng-repeat in view)

```
ng-init="check(item)"
```

Checking will try see if the driver is female and is over 18 years to change the drive status to true, that is our condition while showing the items in view.

```
$scope.check = function(item){

if(item.age > 18 && item.gender === 'female'){
    item.canDrive = true;
} else {
    item.canDrive = false;
}
```

}

If you change the driver gender we save that change and do the check again.

```
   $scope.changeGen = function(gen, item){
    item.gender = gen;
    $scope.check(item);
```

}

I have added a click function on canDrive radio input to change the status as you please.

```
   $scope.changeDriveSts = function(item){
    //toggle val
  item.canDrive = !item.canDrive;
```

}

Hope it helps!

Comment: `ng-checked` should not be used together with `ng-model` : [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)